# How can I migrate users between firebase databases?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase test project with some data in the database. I would like to migrate this data to the production database. I can export/import the JSON data, but the user ids will be wrong since authenticating to the new project creates different ids.

How can I import users from one project to another keeping `uid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way with any of the existing identity providers in Firebase Authentication to have the same UIDs between projects. The only way to get control over the UID is to [implement your own identity provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll have to find a way to let users export and import data on the client.